# Erro na exibição de Pagina - Django

Tags: html, django, formulário, python-2.7

No Django estou desenvolvendo um projeto de uma Biblioteca! (Sou Iniciante no Django, nunca trabalhei com desenvolvimento web)

Resumindo tenho no arquivo models.py  um model Biblioteca e um model Livro, no model Livro existe uma ForeignKey de Biblioteca.

O projeto inteiro esta no [GitHub](https://github.com/Sniickers/Two), lá pode ser visualizado o models.py, forms.py e views.py

Marcado de vermelho na imagem, esta o erro gerado na minha pagina.

[image: Erro no HTML]

Código da Minha template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load staticfiles %}

{% block title %}Chameleon | Cadastro de Livro{% endblock %}

{% block Estilo %}
<link href="{% static 'css/cadastros.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
{% endblock %}

{% block Corpo %}       
<div class="container">

  <form class="form-signin" role="form" action="." method="post"> {% csrf_token %}
    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Cadastro</h2>

    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="codigo" name= "codigo" placeholder="Codigo" required autofocus>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="titulo" name= "titulo" placeholder="Titulo" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="autor" name= "autor" placeholder="Autor" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="editora" name= "editora" placeholder="Editora" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="genero" name= "genero" placeholder="Genero" required>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="publicacao" name= "publicacao" placeholder="Ano: 0000" required>


    <textarea id="sinopse" name="sinopse" placeholder="Sinopse" rows = 10 cols = 63 required></textarea><hr>

    <select id="biblioteca" name="biblioteca">
        <option value="" selected="selected"> ------------- </option>
        <option value="{{ form.biblioteca }}" selected="selected"></option>
    </select><hr>

    <br><p><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Salvar</button></p>
  </form>

</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block JScript %}
{% endblock %}
```

Quando eu exibo o código fonte da pagina a parte da tag `<select>` esta assim:

```
<!-- Inicio Select --> 
<select id="id_biblioteca" name="biblioteca">

    <option value="" selected="selected"> ------------- </option>
    <option value= "<select id="id_biblioteca" name="biblioteca"><option value="" selected="selected">---------</option><option value="1">Chameleon</option></select>" selected="selected"></option>

</select><hr>
<!-- Fim Select -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sua ForeignKey de Biblioteca no Livro significa que um livro pode estar/existir em mais de uma biblioteca?

Troque todo seu `<select>` por apenas `{{ form.biblioteca }}` que então o django imprimirá:

```
<select id="id_biblioteca" name="biblioteca">
    <option value="" selected="selected">---------</option>
    <option value="1">Chameleon</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Significa que uma Biblioteca pode ter varios livros!